# I am unable to install wine in pop os

Tags: terminal, apt, sudo, wine

```
mkdir wine
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘wine’: File exists
goku@pop-os:~$ cd wine
goku@pop-os:~/wine$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=-/wine/testbottle winetricks

Command 'winetricks' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install winetricks

goku@pop-os:~/wine$ sudo apt install winetricks
[sudo] password for goku: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cabextract fonts-wine fuseiso gcc-9-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libblkid1 libblkid1:i386
  libbsd0:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386
  libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
  libgd3:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgpg-error-l10n
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgsm1 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu63:i386 libidn2-0:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm9:i386
  libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmount1 libmount1:i386
  libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses6:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386
  libogg0:i386 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libsensors5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0 libsndio7.0:i386 libsqlite3-0
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libudev1:i386
  libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
  libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386
  libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p7zip p7zip-full wine wine32:i386 wine64 zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  gvfs:i386 glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 rng-tools:i386 libgd-tools:i386
  gnutls-bin:i386 gphoto2:i386 gpm:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386
  libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 jackd2:i386 libmyodbc
  odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386
  tdsodbc:i386 unixodbc-bin:i386 libportaudio2 libportaudio2:i386
  opus-tools:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
  libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 lm-sensors:i386 sndiod
  sndiod:i386 ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386
  opencl-icd opencl-icd:i386 p7zip-rar q4wine winbind playonlinux wine-binfmt
  dosbox exe-thumbnailer | kio-extras wine32-preloader:i386 wine64-preloader
  tor unrar-free | unrar
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cabextract fonts-wine fuseiso gcc-9-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbsd0:i386
  libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libcdparanoia0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386
  libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgsm1 libgsm1:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu63:i386 libidn2-0:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm9:i386
  libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmount1:i386 libmpg123-0:i386
  libncurses6:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386
  libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386
  libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsensors5:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsndio7.0 libsndio7.0:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libudev1:i386 libunistring2:i386
  libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386
  libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p7zip p7zip-full wine wine32:i386 wine64 winetricks
  zlib1g:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libblkid1 libmount1 libsqlite3-0 libuuid1
4 upgraded, 184 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.2 MB/117 MB of archives.
After this operation, 928 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4  eoan-updates/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 libblkid1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6  eoan-updates/main i386 libmount1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 libuuid1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:8 eoan-security/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.29.0-2ubuntu0.2
Ign:9 eoan-security/main i386 libsqlite3-0 i386 3.29.0-2ubuntu0.2
Err:10  eoan/universe amd64 cabextract amd64 1.9-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11  eoan/universe amd64 fuseiso amd64 20070708-3.2build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:12 eoan/main i386 libfreetype6 i386 2.9.1-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:13 eoan-updates/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~19.10.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:14eoan-updates/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~19.10.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'



E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
goku@pop-os:~/wine$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
goku@pop-os:~/wine$ --fix-missing?
--fix-missing?: command not found
goku@pop-os:~/wine$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=-/wine/testbottle winetricks

Command 'winetricks' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install winetricks

goku@pop-os:~/wine$
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get update` needs to run as root. So `sudo apt-get update`.

`--fix-missing` is an option to `apt update`. So `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

It also looks like the repo is missing. Are you connected to the internet?